# Operator norm, convolution and Gauss-Weierstrass kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let be $g_{t}(x)=\frac{1}{\left( 4\pi t\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}%
}{4t}},t>0,x\epsilon
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
,$ Gauss-Weierstrass kernel.

For operator
\begin{equation*}
T_{t}:L_{p}\left(
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
\right) \rightarrow L_{p}\left(
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
\right) ,\left( T_{t}f\right) y=\int\nolimits_{%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
}g_{t}\left( y-x\right) f\left( x\right) dx
\end{equation*}
calculate $\left\Vert T_{t}\right\Vert .$

I know to show that the operator T is linear and bounded and that the upper bound for $T_t$ is $\left\Vert T_{t}\right\Vert \leq 1$.

But how to show that lower bound for $T_t$ is $\left\Vert T_{t}\right\Vert \geq 1$.I do not know how to show it.

Comment: Try taking a sequence $f_n$ where $f_n$ is constant on $[-n, n]$, decays to zero and $\|f_n\|_{L_p} = 1$. Show $T_t f_n \rightarrow f_n$.

Answer (score 1):

The heat equation decreases $L^p$ norm by diffusing the function along the real line. Michael suggested looking at a very flat function, which will not change much by diffusion during time $t$.

Another version of this idea is to use a flat Gaussian function: the advantage is that the heat equation preserves the Gaussian shape. First, calculate the $L^p$ norm of the fundamental solution $g_t$ itself:
$$\begin{split}
\int_{\mathbb R}g_t^p(x)\,dx &= (4\pi t)^{-p/2} \int_{\mathbb R} \exp\left(-\frac{px^2}{4t}\right)\,dx = (4\pi)^{-p/2}p^{-1/2} t^{(1-p)/2} \int_{\mathbb R} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)\,dx \\
&= C  t^{(1-p)/2}
\end{split}
$$
Since the $L^p$ norm of $g_t$ decays like a power function, $\|g_{s+t}\|_p/\|g_{s}\|_p\to 1$ as $s\to \infty$, for any fixed $t$. Since $g_{s+t}=T_t g_s$, the conclusion follows.

Comment: One my fellow suggested to me to show that for continuos functions f with compact suport $T_t f\rightarrow f $ in the $\parallel\cdot\parallel_{\infty} and \parallel\cdot\parallel_{p}$ norms. The density of these functions in $L_p$ and the uniform boundedness of the operators $T_t$ implies that we actually have $T_t f\rightarrow f $ for $t\rightarrow 0 $ for all $t$ from $L_p$
This shows  that $liminf_{t\rightarrow 0}\parallel\ T_t \parallel \geq 1.$
Now one has to show that $\parallel\ T_t \parallel$  is independent of $t$.
But I don't know to prove this. Does anyone know?

Comment: @Amy I think the easiest way to show that $\|T_t\|$ is independent of $t$ is to show that it is equal to $1$ for all $t$.

Comment: Yes, but how to do it?Perhaps using the fact that $g_t$ is Dirac family?

Comment: @Amy You said you already know how to prove $\|T_t\|\le 1$. I described one way to prove the reverse inequality, Michael gave another. Combined, this is a proof that  $\|T_t\|\equiv 1$. ... If you are looking for a proof that shows that $\|T_t\|$ is constant without telling you the value of that constant, you are looking for a hard way to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, I do not know to show $\parallel\ T_t \parallel \geq 1$, but these are just ideas (my answers). I do not know if they are correct. I'm looking for the simplest way to prove that $\parallel\ T_t \parallel \geq 1$